# Force boot from USB stick without BIOS access

Tags: live-usb

Need to create a bootable USB stick using UnetBootin.
Once I have the USB startup created, how do i force my PC to boot from it?

I CANNOT access the bios because there is no video display currently.(my reason for creating the bootable USB stick in the first place)

Comment: By video display do you mean monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Temporarily disconnect the hard drive(s) by unplugging the hard drive's connecting cable, and the computer will boot from the USB flash drive without needing to access the BIOS first.

If that doesn't work and there is still no video display maybe the monitor is broken or disconnected. Try connecting a different monitor or connecting the monitor to the computer with a different cable.